# How to get updated vm after use vue.js and axios?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})

console.log(vm.info)
//Why vm.info is null? I think it has already been overrided.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Why vm.info is null? I think it has already been overrided.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

When I only use vue.js, this can be overrided.

How can I get the updated vm.info?

Answer (score 4):

Because `axios.get` is an asynchronous method, `console.log` is executed before the info is updated; To check the updated info, you'll have to chain a `then` method after `axios.get(...)`, something like `axios.get(...).then(...).then(() => console.log(this.info))`.

Comment: You'll have to call that function after `axios`. For instance, `axios.get.then().then(myFunctionToExecute)`.

Comment: I guess it. Thanks.